# How to add the data from pubnub server to a listview in xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.ios

I am getting an error in my logfile

> [0:] Binding: 'Usermessage' property not found on 'Saileela:        Testmessage', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'

```
private void MessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
{
    _chatWindowViewModel.Usermessage = e.Message;
    _chatWindowViewModel.MessagesList.Add(e.Message);
}
```

And my listview is:

```
<ListView x:Name="Listview" ItemsSource="{Binding MessagesList}">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell>
                  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                      <Label Text="{Binding Usermessage}" FontSize="15"/>
                  </StackLayout>
              </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and my view model is:

```
namespace MobileChat.ViewModels.Chat
{
    public class ChatWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _message;
        private ObservableCollection<string> _messageslist = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ChatWindowViewModel()
        {
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> MessagesList
        {
            get { return _messageslist;}
            set{_messageslist = value;OnPropertyChanged();}
        }

        public string Usermessage
        {
            get { return _message; }
            set{_message = value;OnPropertyChanged();}
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: set your ListView ItemSource to an ObservableCollection.  Whenever you receive a new message, just add it to that collection.  Data binding should do the rest for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MessagesList is a **string** List.

In your code , the label binding path is **MessagesList.Usermessage** , however the path is invalid , because there was no model in the list.

Modify your code :

```
<Label Text="{Binding }" FontSize="15"/>
```